# Changing background color of SignatureView

Tags: android, android-canvas

I found this code on stack and it works well. However, there is an issue. While I'm able to set its background color, the color changes to black as soon as the **clearSignature()** function is called.

Why is that happening?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * A simple view to capture a path traced onto the screen. Initially intended to
 * be used to captures signatures.
 * 
 * @author Andrew Crichton
 * @version 0.1
 */
public class SignatureView extends View
{
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint bgPaint = new Paint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private float curX, curY;

    private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 4;

    boolean modified = false;

    public SignatureView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        setFocusable(true);
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void setSigColor(int color)
    {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setSigColor(int a, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        mPaint.setARGB(a, red, green, blue);
    }

    public boolean clearSignature()
    {
        if (mBitmap != null)
            createFakeMotionEvents();
        if (mCanvas != null)
        {
            mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            mCanvas.drawPaint(bgPaint);
            mPath.reset();
            invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage()
    {
        return this.mBitmap;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public boolean hasChanged()
    {
        return modified;
    }

    @Override protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight)
    {
        int bitmapWidth = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
        int bitmapHeight = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
        if (bitmapWidth >= width && bitmapHeight >= height)
            return;
        if (bitmapWidth < width)
            bitmapWidth = width;
        if (bitmapHeight < height)
            bitmapHeight = height;
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();
        newCanvas.setBitmap(newBitmap);
        if (mBitmap != null)
            newCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        mBitmap = newBitmap;
        mCanvas = newCanvas;
    }

    private void createFakeMotionEvents()
    {
        MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                1f, 1f, 0);
        MotionEvent upEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1f,
                1f, 0);
        onTouchEvent(downEvent);
        onTouchEvent(upEvent);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        modified = true;
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchDown(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * ---------------------------------------------------------- Private
     * methods ---------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void touchDown(float x, float y)
    {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        curX = x;
        curY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y)
    {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - curX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - curY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)
        {
            mPath.quadTo(curX, curY, (x + curX) / 2, (y + curY) / 2);
            curX = x;
            curY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp()
    {
        mPath.lineTo(curX, curY);
        if (mCanvas == null)
        {
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have updated the original SignatureView code, now it supports a custom signature background color. This color is different from the view's background color!

```
setSigBackgroundColor()
```

I also made some other optimizations, use on your own risk as this is minimal tested!

Small list of optimizations:

- Better bitmap recycling etc.
- Recycling of MotionEvents
- Added signature background color set method
- Optimizations
- Changed setImage method, although still not very safe to use!

**New code:**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * A simple view to capture a path traced onto the screen. Initially intended to
 * be used to captures signatures.
 * 
 * @author Andrew Crichton
 * @version 0.1.1
 * 
 * Modified by Rolf Smit
 * -Recycle bitmaps
 * -Recycle MotionEvents
 * -Signature Background color changes
 * -Optimizations
 * -Changed setImage method, although still unsafe to use!
 */
public class SignatureView extends View {

    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private int sigBackgroundColor = Color.TRANSPARENT;

    private float curX, curY;

    private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 4;

    boolean modified = false;

    public SignatureView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void setSigColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setSigColor(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {
        mPaint.setARGB(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    public void setSigBackgroundColor(int color){
        sigBackgroundColor = color;
    }

    public void setSigBackgroundColor(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue){
        sigBackgroundColor = Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    public boolean clearSignature() {
        if (mBitmap != null) {
            createFakeMotionEvents();
        }
        if (mCanvas != null) {
            mCanvas.drawColor(sigBackgroundColor);
            mPath.reset();
            invalidate();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap);
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        this.mBitmap = bitmap;
        if(mCanvas != null){
            mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasChanged() {
        return modified;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
        int bitmapWidth = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
        int bitmapHeight = mBitmap != null ? mBitmap.getWidth() : 0;
        if (bitmapWidth >= width && bitmapHeight >= height) {
            return;
        }
        if (bitmapWidth < width) {
            bitmapWidth = width;
        }
        if (bitmapHeight < height) {
            bitmapHeight = height;
        }
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas();
        newCanvas.setBitmap(newBitmap);

        mCanvas = newCanvas;

        if (mBitmap != null) {
            newCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            mBitmap.recycle();
        } else {
            newCanvas.drawColor(sigBackgroundColor);
        }
        mBitmap = newBitmap;
    }

    private void createFakeMotionEvents() {
        MotionEvent downEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1f, 1f, 0);
        MotionEvent upEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1f, 1f, 0);
        onTouchEvent(downEvent);
        onTouchEvent(upEvent);
        downEvent.recycle();
        upEvent.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        modified = true;
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchDown(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchMove(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp();
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    private void touchDown(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        curX = x;
        curY = y;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - curX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - curY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(curX, curY, (x + curX) / 2, (y + curY) / 2);
            curX = x;
            curY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(curX, curY);
        if (mCanvas == null) {
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I was able to change the background color before as well. Problem is, when the clearSignature function is called (you can see it in the class) it makes the background Black, not the color I specify.

Comment: That's because the clear function calls the drawColor(Color.BLACK) method. It's very obvious the view because black than right?

Comment: I've changed the onDraw method too. Still black.

Comment: What color do you want to view to be? Transparent?

Comment: Yup that's awesome. Just changed the stroke color to black and the background color to white and its working perfectly.

Can you briefly explain the changes you made? And why its working now while it wasn't before?

Comment: The call mCanvas.drawColor did work, but was overridden by the line the mCanvas.drawPaint. The drawPaint call is not actually needed as a drawColor will do the job just fine. So I removed it including the bgPaint field.